# gráfico barras apiladas junto a graficas lineares:

Tags: python

estoy tratando de poder generar la siguiente gráfica en python o algo parecido y el motivo de la consulta es más pedir una orientación sobre que librerías me podrían recomendar para poder realizar la gráfica.

De la gráfica identifico que se trata de barras apiladas, sin embargo cada columna tiene escalas diferentes(independientes)  y por otra parte se sumas gráficas lineares (en rojo y negro) entre las barras.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida! muchas gracias!

[image: Grafica de Barras apiladas]

Comment: Que intentaste hasta ahora?... ten en cuenta que si pides sugerencias, haces que den sus opiniones, lo que esta mal visto por la comunidad... ve a [ask] para mas informacion